# Convert string to array and then represent every letter by a modulo 26 number

Tags: ruby

Bit stuck here.

I just can't find a way to attack this problem.

I want to convert a string into an array of letters which is simple enough with a quick:

```
"X marks the spot".chars #=> ["X", " ", "m", "a", "r", "k", "s", " ", "t", "h", "e", " ", "s", "p", "o", "t"]
```

Then I want to represent each letter in the array by a number modulo 26. (e.g. A = 0, B = 1, ..., Z = 25 and space = 26) in a new array.

Would love some help!

Comment: Show us what you've tried to solve this.

Comment: Please edit to state whether the mapping is case-sensitive, and if it is (which I doubt), how you want lower-case letters to map.  No need to reply--I'll be deleting this comment.

Comment: 26 modulo 26 isn't 26 but 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?:

```
"X marks the spot".upcase.chars.map {|c|c.ord < 65 && 26 || c.ord - 65 }
# => [23, 26, 12, 0, 17, 10, 18, 26, 19, 7, 4, 26, 18, 15, 14, 19]
```

NOTE: Please in future show to the community your solution first.

Answer (score 2):

Do as below :

```
hsh = Hash[('a'..'z').zip (0..25).to_a].merge({" " => 26})
s = "X marks the spot"
s.downcase.chars.map { |i| hsh[i] }
# => [23, 26, 12, 0, 17, 10, 18, 26, 19, 7, 4, 26, 18, 15, 14, 19]
```

Comment: Here are two variants on your calculation of `hsh`, though I prefer what you have: `hsh = Hash[(Array('a'..'z') << ' ').zip (0..26).to_a]` and `25.times.with_object(["`\``", {' '=>26}]) { |i,(f,h)| h[f.succ!] = i }.last`.  In the second, the first block argument is a single backtick in quotes (`('a'.ord-1).chr => backtick`).

Answer (score 1):

```
orig = "X marks the spot"
res = orig.upcase.unpack('C*').map {|c| c==32 ? 26 : c-65}

puts res.inspect
# ⇒ "[23, 26, 12, 0, 17, 10, 18, 26, 19, 7, 4, 26, 18, 15, 14, 19]"
```

Comment: +1 for `unpack`, a method I need to better understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way

```
"X marks the spot".each_byte do |byte|
    puts byte %26
end
```

Of course, you wan store it in an array instead of printing it;)

Comment: `"X marks the spot".each_byte.inject([]) do |acc,byte|;
  acc << byte%26;
end`

Comment: @Darek, I think that needs to be `"X marks the spot".upcase.each_byte.inject([]) { |acc,byte| acc << (byte == 32 ? 26 : (byte - 65) % 26 ) }`.

Comment: @cary-swoveland Assuming that OP want it `upcase`d, you are right.